# Mathematical Sequence Based on Prime Numbers

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

This sequence is based on prime numbers

Hint 1:

> All the Primes have only two digits.

```
16, 17, 11, 16, 10, 8, 13, 7, 14, 8, 

11, 7, 5, 10, 4, 11, 5, 10, ?, ?, ?
```

What are the final three numbers?

Comment: Are they all different?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: So somehow they represent the 21 two-digit primes, three of them missing.

Comment: That’s right!...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3 missing numbers are

> 8, 4, 2

The Sequence is

> the Cross sum of the 21 2-digits Prime numbers in Reverse Order
>  97 is 16, 89 is 17, 83 is 11 and so on  until 17 is 8, 13 is 4 and 11 is 2

Comment: Excellent,,,..got it...SOD(Sum of Digits) series starting from the normal order can be found in oeis..usually reverse series are not usually found.